# : not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, class

I have a dialogContent TemplateSelector for my button to open a dialog. I am getting this error;

> Error 2   'CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs.DialogContentTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(object, System.Windows.DependencyObject)': not all code paths return a value   C:\Users\2337704\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CentralPrintUnitSystem\CentralPrintUnitSystem\Dialogs\DialogContentTemplateSelector.cs   22  53  CentralPrintUnitSystem

My code for the DialogContentTemplateSelector is;

```
namespace CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs
{
    public class DialogContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (item != null && container != null)
            {
                if (item is CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs.EditNewEntryDialogView)
                {
                    return element.FindResource("EditNewEntryDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }

                if (item is   CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs.EditNewDepartmentDialogView)
                {
                    return element.FindResource("CreateNewDepartmentDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Swap the line below the last return Nulll so the } is above the last return Null and the last return null is below it.  The issue is the last return null is currently unreachable code and will never be executed. As it falls into the scope of your IF.  This means this method doesnt always have a return value.

Comment: This is one of the most obvious error to fix. If you just take a bit of your time to look at the related column on the right of the page you could find thousands of questions/answers about this

Comment: David Beaumont, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Well this should fix this error --

```
public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
                FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
                if (item != null && container != null)
            {

                if (item is CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs.EditNewEntryDialogView)
            {

                return element.FindResource("EditNewEntryDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

                if (item is   CentralPrintUnitSystem.Dialogs.EditNewDepartmentDialogView)
            {

                return element.FindResource("CreateNewDepartmentDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            return null;
            }
        return null;
        }
```